# Flask and Azure message queues

Tags: python, flask, message-queue

How can I use `azure.servicebus` with flask?

I Tried to use asyncio to run `process_queue` function, but it locked REST requests.

Now, I'm trying to use `multiprocessing`, but never executes the `print("while True")`.

I'm looking for any good practice to use flask and azure message-queues (or message queues in general way).

My code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from flask import Flask
from src.flask_settings import DevConfig
from src.rest import health
from src.rest import helloworld
import time

def create_app(config_object=DevConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)

    app.register_blueprint(health.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(helloworld.blueprint)

    return app


print("1")
from azure.servicebus import QueueClient, Message

# Create the QueueClient
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string("Endpoint=sb://**********.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=*************", "queue1")


# Receive the message from the queue
def process_queue(sleep_time):
    while True:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        print("while True")
        with queue_client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver:
            messages = queue_receiver.fetch_next(timeout=3)
            for message in messages:
                print(message)
                message.complete()
p = Process(target=process_queue, args=(1, ))
p.start()
p.join()

print("2")
```

Thanks

Comment: did you get this done successfully?

Comment: @wwnde no, I didn't solve this, then I split into two different scripts